# How can I get the main text of CAknDoubleLargeStyleListBox control

Tags: symbian

I have a listbox control in symbian of type `CAknDoubleLargeStyleListBox`, and I want to get the selected item Main text, Not the icon index or the secondary text.How can I do that knowing that the item consists of "`Icon Index \t Main Text \t Secondary Text`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks Abhijith for your help, I found also a great solution in symbian to do the job just in one line.

```
static IMPORT_C TInt ColumnText(TPtrC &aColumnText, TInt aColumn, const TDesC *aSourceText, TChar aColumnSeparator=KColumnListSeparator);

TextUtils::ColumnText(Returned Column,Column Number, Whole text, Delimiter)
```

More information could be found in Symbian S60 3rd Ed SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to manually parse the Descriptor.

```
TBufC<128> string = "Icon Index \t Main Text \t Secondary Text"
int firstSeparator =  string.Find(_L("\t"));
int secondSeparator = string.Right( string.Length() - firstSeparator -2).Find(_L("\t")); 
secondSeparator+= firstSeparator;

TBuf<128> mainString = string.Mid(firstSeparator,secondSeparator);
```

You might have to fine tune the code to eliminate compile errors.